# How to fix "Enum does not name a type" error message in C++

Tags: c++, enums

C++ compiler produces error code: 'color' does not name a type
I included all relevant code for the problem.
The error message only appears with the function declaration in the cpp file

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"
Color Card::getColor() {return color;}
```

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
enum Color{purple, orange};

private:
int rank = 0;
int value = 0;
Color color = purple;

public:
Color getColor();
```

Comment: Outside of `class Card`, your enum is spelled `Card::Color`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not that you function definition is in header or source file, but if it is inside `class Card` or not. You will have exactly the same problem if you try to define function inside of header but outside of class definition. Solution is simple, you have to refer `enum Color` as inner type of `class Card`:

```
Card::Color Card::getColor() {return color;}
```